# Where can I find the ASP.Net MVC2 combo box?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, combobox

I can't find it in the toolbox anywhere. What control do I have available that is similar to a Windows Forms combo box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has a decent page describing the various helpers included out of the box: [RenderingForm in ASP.NET MVC Using HTML Helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx). Probably the closest to what you are looking for would be the DropDownList, whcich renders the html `<select>` tag.